# Windows Phone App entry point and starting up timeout

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1, cmake, cross-platform

I'm curently working on a multi-platform app (C++, WindowsPhone 8.1), the kind with lots of #ifdef PLATFORM, that deals with settings up the platform specifics things and then just run the common code from an external library.

I have been working a lot with Windows Phone, but as far as I know, Windows Phone App entry point is the void App::OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs^ e). In the project I'm working on, the app start with a int main(int ac, char **av).

When ran through the debugger, the app starts and run properlly until it gets to the end of the main, and then just close itself. When when I'm trying to deploy from command line, (AppDeployCmd.exe) I get a "Error: The app didn't start." error message.

I think it is because of the way Windows Phone OS handle app launching. Most mobile apps are running in an infinite loop polling event from the touchscreen, this one just run as a classic old-school app, and I think because the main thread is busy computing stuff instead of polling event, Windows consider the app to be stuck and just kills it.

But as I said, I'm pretty much new to Windows developpement and I may be wrong about all this.

Can anyone confirm this theory ? Else what could cause the "Error: The app didn't start." (from AppDeployCmd.exe).

Best regards, Pierre